# Genymotion Virtual device got no IP Address after Visual studio Install

Tags: networking, windows-10, virtualbox, genymotion

I have been using genymotion emulator for a while now. It was working fine, but after installing Visual Studio Community on windows 10 I am getting the following

[image: Genymotion error]

I have set the ip of the device as show
Under **virtualbox>file>preferences>network** I have the following

[image: Virtual box Network details 1]

[image: Virtual box Network details 2]

And After selecting the device **settings>network** I have the following

[image: Settings network 1]

[image: Settings network 2]

After installing Visual Studio I have the following Hyper-v adapters under network

[image: Hyper-v adapters]

I also uninstalled virtual box and genymotion and did a fresh install. After which I download a new device as well.

Also i tried reducing the memory of the virtual device as it was mentioned as a solution for this on the web.

I can't figure out what is the problem.

Kindly point me in the right direction

-Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, it's because you installed Windows Phone SDK and his emulators.

If you don't need Hyper-V, disable it and all will work again.

A link to disable hyper-v : http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-windows_install/how-do-i-uninstall-hyper-v/7d268911-47cd-4c52-bfe5-ea41e58067ab?auth=1

Answer (score 0):

The responsible thing that is assigning dynamic IPs for you is called DHCP server so you have to enable it to resolve this issue.

Try the following:

Solution1 :-

Open VirtualBox's Preferences and under Network section, check the adapter named "vboxnet0" in "Host-Only Networks", double click on it and make sure to apply the following configuration there.

6- Double click on that name and apple the following configuration

Adapter Tab:

```
IPv4 Adapter: 192.168.65.1

IPV4 Network Mask: 255.255.255.0
```

DHCP Server Tab:

```
Check "Enable Server"

HINT: THIS RESOLVES YOUR PROBLEM, BUT OTHERS IS REQUIRED TO AVOID OTHER PROBLEMS

Server Address: 192.168.65.100

Server Mask: 255.255.255.0

Lower Address Bound: 192.168.65.101

Higher Address Bound: 192.168.65.255
```

Note: make sure you don't have any other adapter with the same configuration that might cause conflicts . revise all of adapters in that section, "Host-Only Networks" I mean, and delete the same ones there.

you can check out these tutorial also [genymotionissue](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wEmfUxwQUgY).

Solution2 :-

Reduce the memory below 50% of the total memory. And now it will works.Here i had found one more solution to your problem http://androidcodex.net/unable-to-start-the-virtual-device-genymotion/